# Solving for a negative exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Is it possible to solve for a negative exponent?  If so, can someone help me get the **n** on one side of the equation?

I'm not a math student and I have no math teacher connections so I thought I would turn here when I was unable to find the answer myself on Google.

> The equation calculates monthly car payments ($m$) from interest rate ($i$), principal ($p$) and number of months ($n$).  I figured out how to solve for $p$ if I have all the other values.  I assume $i$ is impossible to solve for, but $n$ looked like it might be possible.
>
> ?I'm not really sure about the math terms either if someone wants to help and put the correct tags.
>
> $$\frac{\frac{i}{12}\times p}{1-\left(1+\frac{i}{12}\right)^{-n}} = m$$

Comment: If you know all the other values, you can find  $n$, using logarithms

Comment: Any idea what that equation might look like?

Comment: You could multiply both sides of the equation by the denominator in order to cancel it on the left side. Then, isolate the term with the $n$ on the right side, and take a logarithm of both sides. Then you can bring down the n and divide by the logarithm to completely isolate $n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$a^{-b} = \frac{1}{a^b}$